# Complex SO(n) and Degenerations

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, complex-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let's say you have a matrix $A\in\Bbb C^{n\times n}$ with $A^T A = 0$, like for example this one:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -i \\ i & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
I ask the following:

> **Question:** Is there a sequence of matrices $(S_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ with $S_k^T\cdot S_k = I$ and $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} S_k A = 0$ ?

For the matrix above, you can pick $\theta_k:=k\cdot(1-i)$ and
$$
S_k = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta_k) & -\sin(\theta_k) \\ \sin(\theta_k) & \cos(\theta_k) \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This is not entirely obvious, but a straightforward computation. I say that because a computer algebra system did it.

PS: I have somewhat involved reasons to ask this question, and laying them out would basically just yield many paragraphs full of buzzwords, and I do not think it would make the question any more clear. I do believe that the answer is affirmative, though.

**Edit:** I decided to add at least a few buzzwords. Let $O_n=\{ S\in\mathbb C^{n\times n} \mid S^T S = I \}$ be the orthogonal group. It is a reductive group acting on the space $W=\Bbb C^{n\times n}$ by left multiplication. I am asking whether the Nullcone of this action is equal to $N=\{ A \mid A^T A = 0 \}$. Note that $N$ is closed and certainly contains the Nullcone, because if a sequence $(S_k)$ with the above property exists, then $A^TA=A^TS_k^TSA=(S_kA)^T(S_kA)\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$, which means $A^TA=0$.

Comment: In your question you have a matrix $S$, should that also be $S_k$?  Also, I'm pretty sure your example doesn't work, I think $lim \ S_kA = A$ for the matrices you have written.

Comment: @Nate: Thanks and sorry, I got confused and wrote $\frac1k$ instead of $k$, this example should work now. Also, yes, I want all of the $S_k$ to be orthogonal. Fixed that, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is affirmative.

I should have done some literature research. In fact, this is the **First Fundamental Theorem for $\operatorname{O}_n$ and $\operatorname{SO}_n$**, as can be found in the book [*Classical Invariant Theory - A Primer*](http://jones.math.unibas.ch/~kraft/docs/primernew.pdf) by Kraft & Procesi, page 117.

The proof is quite clever and not too hard, but let me just describe how you get my version from the statement of the theorem in the book:

Take $p=n$, so we are looking at the invariants on $(\Bbb C^n)^n = \Bbb C^{n\times n}$. You can check that the action they describe is left-multiplication by matrices. According to the theorem, the invariants for this action are the maps 
\begin{align*}
f_{ij}:\Bbb C^{n\times n} &\longrightarrow \Bbb C
\\ A=(A_{k,\ell}) & \longmapsto \sum_{k=1}^n A_{ki} A_{kj}
\end{align*}
i.e. you take the inner product of the $i$-th and $j$-th column of $A$. Now, $A$ is in the Nullcone if and only if $f_{ij}(A)=0$ for all $1\le i\le j\le n$ and this precisely means $A^TA=0$.